# Same network same switch but computers can't talk "ping"to eachother

Tags: networking, ping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does IPv4 Subnetting Work?](https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work)

Each computer(all 2 of them) can ping the router but can't ping each-other and firewall is off. Same default gateway, IP address very similar (just two number away at end) but the subnet mask is different between these two computers. One ends in 192 the other 224. There is a switch between them that then connects to the router.
Why can't the computers ping each-other?

Comment: Hi Sue, your question will likely get moved to SuperUser or closed, this is a site for professionals. Your subnet masks should match, this will probably resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the inconsistent subnet masks, one of the computers may think it's on the same network as the other, while the other thinks it is on a different network and needs to route via its default gateway. A successful round-trip ping is impossible in this scenario.

Setting both computers to whichever subnet mask is correct will solve the problem.